# Large files on Pantheon

Tags: files

I run the website for a small nonprofit, and we're looking at Pantheon.  I've imported my code and DB and gotten things basically working, but I have a question about serving large files.  We're a choir and we have a couple hundred MP3s (recordings of rehearsals, so people can practice) that we need to serve.  It's not high traffic at all - probably only a couple dozen downloads per week - but the files can be as big as 100M each.

A CDN would be overkill - all downloaders are local, not spread around the globe.  And it's really not much traffic.

How should I host them?  Just check them in to Git?  They're not currently in `sites/default/files`, but I could put them there and use symlinks from their current location if that would help.

Comment: There are many solutions out there optimized for hosting media files that integrate really well with Drupal's Media module; Soundcloud, etc. Pantheon's individual file limits are 256mb, so it's worth a try, if there isn't much traffic. They shouldn't be committed to the repo, that will slow down workflow operations. Put them in sites/default/files.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't check them into Git, just create an Audio content type and have a file/audio field. I would just check Pantheon to see what the file upload limit is.